# SPARQL Get all the properties from a Class or an Individual

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

What I want to do is to get the property list from the Individual1 or from a class,
Get all properties from "something"
The result should be something like this (for Secret_Data):

```
| Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance | High                                       |
| Asset_has_Availability_Importance....| Moderate                                   |
| Asset_has_Integrity_Importance.......| Moderate                                   |
| Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent.......| Compromise_sensitive_information           |
| Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent.......| Disclosure_of_sensitive_information        |
| Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent.......| Exploit_exposed_unauthorized_information   |
| Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent.......| Integrity_loss_by_corrupting_critital_data |
```

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Secret_Data">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Data"/>
    <Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">High</Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance>
    <Asset_has_Availability_Importance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Moderate</Asset_has_Availability_Importance>
    <Asset_has_Integrity_Importance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Moderate</Asset_has_Integrity_Importance>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Compromise_sensitive_information"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Disclosure_of_sensitive_information"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Exploit_exposed_unauthorized_information"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Integrity_loss_by_corrupting_critital_data"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="&securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M;Obtain_unauthorized_access"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I think the query is something like this, (But the value is not well formatted, and some properties are not importart like "type property"):

```
PREFIX css:<http://www.semanticweb.org/evalues/ontologies/2014/3/securityOntology_ITESM_UC3M#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?property ?value
WHERE {
  css:Secret_Data ?property ?value.
}
```

Comment: Could you show the actual ontology please?  What you've shown doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  Class, SubClass1, and SubClass2 suggest that you're trying to show a class hierarchy, but Properties aren't classes, nor do they "belong" to classes (the way that a method might belong to a class in a single-dispatch object-oriented programming language).  Please show the data that you've actually got, and tell us what you'd like as the result.

Comment: Ok, I posted an image :D

Comment: That helps, but can you post the actual ontology so that web have something to query against?

Comment: ok, I paste the ontology

Comment: Your last edit completely changes the nature of the question. Before, you'd been asking about getting attributes of restriction superclasses of a class;  now you're asking about getting properties of an individual.

Comment: My bad, I didnt explain it very well, but my question did not change: "What I want to do is to get the property list from an Individual1 or from a class"  In the example shows a property list form an Individual, but classes also could "contain" properties too

Comment: In OWL, classes aren't the subject of object property assertions or datatype property assertions.  They can the subject of annotations, and they can be related to other classes as subclasses, equivalent classes, etc.  In the original version of your question, the **class** Psicology didn't have the properties and values you mentioned, but rather individuals of type Psicology did.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an answer to the updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to updated question (a query about individuals)

It's much easier to answer question with *complete* sample data.  If we bundle up the data that you've given with appropriate namespace declarations, we end up with something like this:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/">
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Secret_Data">
    <Asset_has_Availability_Importance rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Moderate</Asset_has_Availability_Importance>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Data"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Integrity_loss_by_corrupting_critital_data"/>
    <Asset_has_Integrity_Importance rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >Moderate</Asset_has_Integrity_Importance>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Obtain_unauthorized_access"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Disclosure_of_sensitive_information"/>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Compromise_sensitive_information"/>
    <Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >High</Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance>
    <Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/Exploit_exposed_unauthorized_information"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

It's often helpful to view this in Turtle serialization, since it will look more like the query. The data is the same though, and the query will run against the data in either serialization, of course.

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Secret_Data  a  owl:NamedIndividual , :Data ;
        :Asset_has_Availability_Importance
                "Moderate"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
        :Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance
                "High"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
        :Asset_has_Integrity_Importance
                "Moderate"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
        :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent
                :Integrity_loss_by_corrupting_critital_data , :Obtain_unauthorized_access , :Disclosure_of_sensitive_information , :Compromise_sensitive_information , :Exploit_exposed_unauthorized_information .
```

You can use a query like the following:

```
prefix :    <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select distinct ?property ?value where {
  :Secret_Data ?property ?value .
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property                              | value                                       |
=======================================================================================
| rdf:type                              | owl:NamedIndividual                         |
| :Asset_has_Availability_Importance    | "Moderate"^^xsd:string                      |
| rdf:type                              | :Data                                       |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Integrity_loss_by_corrupting_critital_data |
| :Asset_has_Integrity_Importance       | "Moderate"^^xsd:string                      |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Obtain_unauthorized_access                 |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Disclosure_of_sensitive_information        |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Compromise_sensitive_information           |
| :Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance | "High"^^xsd:string                          |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Exploit_exposed_unauthorized_information   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you don't want `rdf:type` in there, you could use `filter ?property != rdf:type`, or if there are multiple properties that you want to exclude, `filter ( ?property NOT IN ( rdf:type … ) )`:

```
prefix :    <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23223447/1281433/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select distinct ?property ?value where {
  :Secret_Data ?property ?value .
  filter ( ?property not in ( rdf:type ) )
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property                              | value                                       |
=======================================================================================
| :Asset_has_Availability_Importance    | "Moderate"^^xsd:string                      |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Integrity_loss_by_corrupting_critital_data |
| :Asset_has_Integrity_Importance       | "Moderate"^^xsd:string                      |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Obtain_unauthorized_access                 |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Disclosure_of_sensitive_information        |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Compromise_sensitive_information           |
| :Asset_has_Confidentiality_Importance | "High"^^xsd:string                          |
| :Asset_threatenedBy_ThreatEvent       | :Exploit_exposed_unauthorized_information   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Answer to the original question (a query about classes)

In the original version of the question, you gave this image of your ontology and asked for results that are after it:

[image]

```
| numberChapters  | 1 |
| numberPages     | 5 |
```

In the RDF/XML serialization of that ontology (since removed from the question), the description of the Psicology class was as follows:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RiMIUJzVuVHCr4Ke4TkFwX">
    <rdfs:label>Psicology</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RDHbMG5sh4tyJ6ZoHwxLBHk"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R9DdxIZDrtXApiHoBJ6NmAy"/>
            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">5</owl:hasValue>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R8WDOefPWzIoTChbjV31ela"/>
            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1</owl:hasValue>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

or in the more human-readable Turtle notation:

```
<http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RiMIUJzVuVHCr4Ke4TkFwX>
        a                owl:Class ;
        rdfs:label       "Psicology" ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  <http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RDHbMG5sh4tyJ6ZoHwxLBHk> ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a               owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:hasValue    5 ;
                           owl:onProperty  <http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R9DdxIZDrtXApiHoBJ6NmAy>
                         ] ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a               owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:hasValue    1 ;
                           owl:onProperty  <http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R8WDOefPWzIoTChbjV31ela>
```

says that Psicology (which is usually spelled Psychology in English, by the way) is a subclass of the class of things that have the value 5 for the property numPages and the things that have the value 1 for the property numChapters.  Psicology is also a subclass of Libray. (Is this supposed to be Library?)

These seem like strange axioms to me, and I wonder if there might be some sort of modeling error going on.  I'm not sure what a Psicology is, but you're saying that for any Psicology p, it's the case that numPages(p,5) and numChapters(p,1).  Is that really what you want to do?

At any rate, given your data, we can retrieve the results that you want.  Looking at the Turtle serialization is useful, because it's very similar to the SPARQL query syntax.  The query you want is:

```
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
prefix :      <http://webprotege.stanford.edu/project/Bnag2Z5E4j78tB27NnLq1L#> 
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

select ?property ?value where {
  ?class rdfs:label "Psicology" ;
         rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:hasValue ?value ; 
                           owl:onProperty [ rdfs:label ?property ] ] .
}
```

```
-------------------------
| property      | value |
=========================
| "numChapters" | 1     |
| "numPages"    | 5     |
-------------------------
```

Comment: My OWL looks strange because is not in a turtle notation, is in RDF/XML, but I need the query to run in this "notation" I change the post to the real "ontology"

Comment: @angel.cazares RDF can be serialized in a number of different formats.  RDF/XML is one;  Turtle is another.  They're serializations of the *same* RDF graph though.  I showed the Turtle serialization because it tends to be closer to the SPARQL syntax.  The query runs against the data in either format.

Comment: I am using a dll for c# that only runs with the RDF/XML sintaxis :(

Comment: @angel.cazares **You don't have to change your data.**  I only *showed* in a different format because it makes it easier to figure out what the **query** should look like.  The SPARQL query I provided  will work just fine with the RDF/XML serialization of your ontology.