# Sparql query to get data property values of a class

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, owl

I have tried a SPARQL query to get a data property and its value of a given class. Ontology is created in Sinhala language and here is the description of class:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R9uiQljpDXJEZ868fnnTGfE">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R8PYsiiP0lkvFeFlpH3aQTP"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R9ZKyvH13cQVwMboXOzwAkx"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/R7d2MyZOxPEpWxXVctrVcgX"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RCDEhkpjMY51Mr6sbD8rJAk"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RC5t0y1e6l6lUULc0l37Xhw"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RGKrLFedeMijO31cz81JC2"/>
            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1</owl:hasValue>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:label>අනූනන විභාජනය</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>
```

I have used python to write queries and retrieve data and here is the query that I have written:

```
my_world = World()
my_world.get_ontology("file://static\\ontology\\root-ontology.owl").load()  # path to the owl file is given here
self.graph = my_world.as_rdflib_graph()

query6 = ("prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
          "base <http://webprotege.stanford.edu/project/C25wqZ4qamhbITLmCGstJ0> "
          "prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
          "SELECT ?domain ?property ?value"
          "WHERE {"
          "rdfs:subClassOf owl:hasValue ?value."
          "owl:onProperty rdfs:label ?property."
          "?domain rdfs:label 'අනූනන විභාජනය'."
          "}")

domain_property_range = self.graph.query(query6)
    for item in domain_property_range:
        prop_label = str(item['property'].toPython())
        prop_label = re.sub(r'.*#', "", prop_label)

        value = str(item['value'].toPython())
        value = re.sub(r'.*#', "", value)
        sentences.append({'property': prop_label, 'value': value})
    print(sentences)
```

but it gives an empty list. I am very new to this sparql queries and rdf stuff.
So it would be much appreciated if somebody could help to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: `"SELECT ?domain ?property ?value"
          "WHERE {"` may be a problem if the lines are simply concentrated.  It could turn into `SELECT ... ?valueWHERE` and you probably don't want that.

Comment: thank you so much for the comment @JoshuaTaylor . But still get the empty list. Actually I tried this query following you answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223447/sparql-get-all-the-properties-from-a-class-or-an-individual/23228465#23228465
But I feel that I haven't convert your turtle notations correctly into sparql one.

Comment: Your query is far away from being correct: `SELECT * WHERE {
?domain rdfs:label "අනූනන විභාජනය" ;
 rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:hasValue ?value ;
          owl:onProperty ?property  ]  } `

Comment: @AKSW it works! Thank you.. But there is a small problem with the answer. I'm getting [{'subject': 'අනූනන විභාජනය', 'predicate': 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/RGKrLFedeMijO31cz81JC2', 'value': '1'}] instead of the label of property. I'll work on it. Thank you again!! :)

Comment: I don't see any label in your sample data... But, just add `?property rdfs:label ?propertyLabel .` to the query - SPARQL is very simple, the only thing you have to do is matching RDF triples by means of triple patterns.

Comment: @AKSW yes I modified the query to get the label. Now it works correctly. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: and could you recommend me some articles or tutorials to refer and learn more about SPARQL and especially how to insert subject, predicate, object data into an ontology? It would be a great support for me to continue my work!! Thank you